# How to merge multiples FileStreamResult into one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf

I'm retrieving multiple PDFs files and I need to append into one single pdf file. This is my code:

```
    public FileStreamResult downloadPdf2(int param)
            {
                if (response.Code == 0)
                {
                    return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(response.Archivo.Contenido), "application/pdf");
                }
                return null;
    
            }

public FileStreamResult downloadPdf1(int param)
            {
                if (response.Code == 0)
                {
                    return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(response.Archivo.Contenido), "application/pdf");
                }
                return null;
    
            }
```

Comment: Appending them one after the other is simple, but that will not get you "one single pdf file" it'll just be a bodge of a bunch of files together. You need a PDF parser to read the pages and re-encode them

Comment: If you want to download both files at once, you can wrap them into a ZIP file and send that.

Comment: the problem is I need to show it at the browser so downloading is not an option

Comment: Then, like @Charlieface said, use a PDF library to merge the PDFs. Beware, though, actual merging invalidates digital signatures, and other document level material also usually is damaged or dropped. (You might try wrapping the PDFs in a portfolio PDF. I don't know, though, whether all PDF viewers in browsers support portfolios. )